# Calculate Frattini Subgroup $\Phi(G)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G:=\langle a,b \rangle$  be the subgroup of $S_8$, where $a=(1,2,3,4)(5,6)$ and $b=(6,7,8)$. By the way it is indeed isomorphically to subdirect product of $C_4$ and $S_4$.

How to see that the Frattini quotient $\Phi(G) := \cap \{M | M $maximal subgroup of $G \}$ equals to $\langle (1,3)(2,4) \rangle$ in maybe more sophisticated way than collecting all possible maximal subgroups? (maybe by reducing it to an intersection of only two maximal groups or similar?)

Comment: Let $N$ be the suibgroup $\langle (1,3)(2,4) \rangle$. As Nicky Hekster points out, $\Phi(S_4)=1$, so the interection of all maximal subgroups containing $N$ is $N$, and hence $\Phi(G) \le N$. If $\Phi(G) \ne N$, then there must be a maximal subgroup intersecting $N$ trivially, which would have to be a complmenet of $N$ in $G$, and have index $2$.But $[G,G] \cong A_4$ with $G/[G,G]$ cyclic of order $4$, so there is no such subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the following facts:

$1$. If $G \cong H \times K$, then $\Phi(G) \cong \Phi(H) \times \Phi(K)$.
$2$. $\Phi(C_4) \cong C_2$, and $\Phi(S_4)=1$.

Comment: Since $G$ is not itself a direct product, it is not dcompeltely clear how this helps. It is also interesting to observe that, although 1 is true for finite groups, it is not true in general. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283989/product-of-frattini-groups.

Comment: Ah, Derek, yes, did not check if the $G$ is actually a direct product, was assuming that. And yes, I know, the direct product rule for Frattini does not carry over to infinite groups.